# How to insert only new records using Linq-to-SQL?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, insert

I have to insert some data periodically in my SQL Server database. But the feeds where I read the data repeats some data that was inserted before. When I use Linq-to-SQL to insert into the DB either some data is duplicated, or a primary key violation exception is raised, depending on the primary key.

How to insert the data without duplications and without exceptions? I don't want to avoid the exception with a try-catch, because once the exception is raised the rest of the data isn't inserted.

**update** I also found my own solution: I wrote a duplicated entries deletion stored procedure, which is run right after the InsertAllOnSubmit + SubmitChanges

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you have to do is create a new instance of your class and then call InsertOnSumbit() on the table:

```
var foo = new MyFoo { Name = "foo1" };
var dc = new MyDataContext();
dc.Foos.InsertOnSubmit(foo);
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

The other thing you need to be sure of is how you're incrementing your ID column. In general, I always make sure to use the IDENTITY(1,1) setting on my ID columns. This is declared on your LINQ entity's id column like so:

```
[Column(AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert, IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
public Int32 Id { get; set; }
```

To avoid duplicates, what you really need is what we call in my shop an "append" functionality. IMHO, this is most easily accomplished with a stored procedure - we even have a template we use for it:

```
USE [<Database_Name, sysobject, Database_Name>]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [<Schema, sysobject, dbo>].[<Table_Name, sysobject, Table_Name>__append]
(
    @id INT OUTPUT,
    @<Key_Param, sysobject, Key_Param> <Key_Param_Type, sysobject, VARCHAR(50)>
)
AS
BEGIN

        SELECT @id = [id] FROM [<Schema, sysobject, dbo>].[<Table_Name, sysobject, Table_Name>s] (NOLOCK) WHERE [<Key_Param, sysobject, Key_Param>] = @<Key_Param, sysobject, Key_Param>

IF @id IS NULL  
BEGIN       
    INSERT INTO [<Schema, sysobject, dbo>].[<Table_Name, sysobject, Table_Name>s] ([<Key_Param, sysobject, Key_Param>]) 
    OUTPUT INSERTED.[id] INTO @inserted_ids
    VALUES (@<Key_Param, sysobject, Key_Param>)

    SELECT TOP 1 @id = [id] FROM @inserted_ids;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE [<Schema, sysobject, dbo>].[<Table_Name, sysobject, Table_Name>s]
    SET
        [<Key_Param, sysobject, Key_Param>] = @<Key_Param, sysobject, Key_Param>
    WHERE [id] = @id
END
END
GO
```

It is possible to do it in linq though, just query for a list of existing IDs (or whatever column you're keying off of):

```
var dc = new MyDataContext();
var existingFoos = dc.Foos.ToList();
var newFoos = new List<Foo>();
foreach(var bar in whateverYoureIterating) {
// logic to add to newFoos 
}
var foosToInsert = newFoos.Where(newFoo => !existingFoos.Any(existingFoo => newFoo.Id == existingFoo.Id));

dc.Foos.InsertAllOnSubmit(foosToInsert);
dc.SubmitChanges();
// use the next line if you plan on re-using existingFoos. If that's the case I'd wrap  dc.SubmitChanges() in a try-catch as well.
existingFoos.AddRange(foosToInsert);
```

Comment: The LINQ solution seems pretty slow. Querying a giant table a loading the contents in memory seems unfeasible for me. Maybe I should stick with the SP approach.

Comment: That's what I figured... Though, you could speed the LINQ solution up by only selecting the properties you really need... for example, just the ID column. Also, if you can re-use the "existing" query for multiple runs, that'll help as well.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no way around it as Linq to SQL does not check the database before it performs the insert. The only way to do this is to query the database *first* to determine if the duplicate record exists and then add the record if it does not.

Ideally Linq to SQL would support the [Ignore Duplicate Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csh347s8(VS.71).aspx) property on a SQL column. But unfortunately it does not at the moment.

Comment: What about in 2018?  Do you know of a way now?